# Stuck at boot screen after release-upgrade from 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: boot, upgrade

Till a week ago I had Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running. In order to upgrade to Ubuntu 23.10 I've allowed "upgrade to any new versions" and did `do-release-upgrade`.

After the upgrade the system does not boot anymore. It shows the error message:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device: Common problems
- Boot args (cat/proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev
Alert! UUID=SOME_UUID does not exist. Dropping to a shell.

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter help for list of built-in commands
(initramfs)
```

The only way to boot the system is to select in grub loader the entry

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0.88-generic
```

(all newer entries does end in the error described above)

I would appreciate any help, what I can do to repair the system.